# Вопрос про android firestore filters

Tags: android, firebase, firestore

У меня в одном проекте есть задача. Нужно в андроид firestore  добавить фильтр, который проверяет, есть ли у обьекта в поле(массив строк) фильтрационная строка
(смысл: query.orderBy("cities").contains(startCity))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понял, такой вид запросов пока не поддерживается.

Если придумаете как, можно использовать Map вместо Array.
Тогда запросы согласно примеров в документации:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays

Или тащить все на клиента и фильтровать уже здесь, пока Firestore не допилят.

Comment: пример тот,где используеться whereEqualTo() ??

Comment: Да, он самый! `whereEqualTo("categories.cats", true)`